# Dynamic Sql - custom built SELECT using a dreaded Cursor - need in VIEW form

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL question that maybe someone can help with.  I wrote a Stored Procedure that examines a CRM entity data extract, finds all PICKLIST fields in it, does CRM optionset lookups on these fields, and returns actual label values as new, appended fields at the end of the resultset.

Problem is, I need this in VIEW form ...   I can't create this as a VIEW (in current form) because as I'm finding out you can't run a VIEW with scripting code... it has to be basically a single SELECT statement.   My other strategy was to maybe create this as a table-valued function,  then select from the FUNCTION in a VIEW, which is allowable... but I can't do that either, as I can't pre-define a temp table in a function, because the number of columns returned in the query is dynamic from entity to entity.  (it's never the same from entity to entity).

Another option would be to write to a global temp table, but I don't think you can't reference global temp tables in functions or view either.

So I have 2 questions... Do you guys know of any hacks to call a stored procedure from a View? .... or...  Would you have any ideas on how to convert this StoredProc (which contains a few variables and a dreaded CURSOR loop - yes I know the drill - never use CURSORS - but I can't figure out how not to in this case) to a single dynamic SELECT statement, which I could then create a VIEW with?  Note that it does have a paramter (which isn't allowed in a View either) - but I'd be ok with hardcoding that in (to create a different view for each entity table I need to use this on).

You'll see in cursor statement below is where I'm selecting the dynamic columns I need to append to my Select query... in the cursor loop is my dynamic sql for this.  Note that this loop will return different column names and number of columns for each entity extract table I run it against.  Running this stored proc returns exactly what I need... for any and all entities I need to run it against .I just need it have it in VIEW form if possible.

Stored Proc code:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[IMS_OptionSetsLookup] 
@azuretable nvarchar(max)
as
declare @entity varchar(max)
declare @column varchar(max)
declare @loopsql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
select am.entityname, c.column_name
from information_schema.columns c
inner join ims_AttributeMetaData am on  am.entityname = substring(c.table_name,5,99)
                                        and am.attributename = c.column_name
where am.AttributeType = 'Picklist' and
        c.table_name = @azuretable

set @loopsql = 'select b.*, '

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @entity, @column
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN   
    set @loopsql = @loopsql + ' (select o.LocalizedLabel from ims_optionsetmetadata o, ' + @azuretable + ' a where o.entityname = ''' + @entity + ''' and optionsetname = ''' + @column + ''' and o.[option] = a.' + @column + ' and a.id = b.id) as ' + @column + '_Value,'    
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @entity, @column
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

set @loopsql = substring(@loopsql,1, len(@loopsql) - 1) + ' from ' + @azuretable + ' b' 
execute sp_executesql @loopsql

GO
```

Comment: A view can't contain dynamic SQL either... Your question would benefit from sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into) and desired results. Perhaps there is another way to get the desired results, but without knowing the sample data and desired result it requires us to reverse engineer your stored procedure, and that's simply too much to ask.

Comment: Dynamics CRM already has views for fetching option set values: _All drop-down lists (option sets) have two associated fields for every string in the list. For each string, there is a value (code) field and a label (name) field, such as, leadsource and leadsourcename. For example, the filtered view for Leads returns two fields related to the LeadSource attribute of type Picklist: LeadSource = 1 and LeadSourceName =“Advertisement”_. I would thus suggest looking at using filtered views https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531161.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks Zohar and Henrik... I'm not querying CRM directly - it's Dynamics 365 online, so I don't have access to the FilteredViews that I had when we were on-prem....  I'm querying data extract tables from a sql azure dbase, which is kept up to date with data extract job.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, it doesn't sound like you care about up to the second information.

Is there something preventing you from Running the usp_ in an Agent job, dumping the results to a table? You could have the Agent job run at an interval or once a day.

Comment: That is indeed my fallback option - but was hoping to avoid creating new tables and replicating all that data...  was hoping I could query my existing extract tables, but with dynamic appended "value" fields.... may not be able to do that with a VIEW. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I've decided to go with this route - having a scheduled job dumping results to a table.  I can then join both tables to return all the data I need in the view.